# Getting Unauthorised Message while passing access token in request

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, access-token

I have created a windows app which is calling some app hosted in azure. App service is using AAD for authentication.
Following is the method I am using for MS login and storing token.

```
authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, new FileCache());
authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
               result = t.Result;
            })
            .Wait();
```

By using this above method, I am successfully able to login using MS credential and getting access token from **result**.

Now I am passing this token in header request to get some data from app which has SSO enabled like :-

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var uri = "http://appservice.azurewebsites.net/api/values/5";

    _auth.GetToken().ContinueWith(t => { token = t.Result; }).Wait();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var TaskAPI = client.GetAsync(uri).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            var response = task.Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                flag = 1;
                var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            }
        }
    });

    TaskAPI .Wait();
}
```

> Get Token function is acquiring token silently

Below is GetToken() used to fetch token for calling API

```
authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(todoListResourceId, clientId)
           .ContinueWith(i =>
                  {
                       result = i.Result;
                  }).Wait(); 

return result.AccessToken;
```

When I call this URI by passing retrieved token, I get response of Un Authorized(401).

How can I check if token is proper or I am missing something or if there is any other way to do that?

Thanks

Subham,Nathcorp

Comment: You should check the `aud` claim in the token matches the valid audience configured in the API. You can use a tool like https://jwt.ms to decode the token.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have checked aud claim and it is valid audience still I am getting un authorized message in response.

Comment: @subham Did you find a solution yet?